# Filter arrays in Javascript and return all related objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I want to filter an array of objects with JavaScript.

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'DetailedWorkingHour' => array(
            'id' => '326',
            'start' => '07:00:00',
            'end' => '16:00:00',
            'date' => '2015-06-17',
            'working_hour_template_id' => '3'
        ),
        'WorkingHourTemplate' => array(
            'color' => 'red',
            'id' => '3'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'DetailedWorkingHour' => array(
            'id' => '346',
            'start' => '07:00:00',
            'end' => '16:00:00',
            'date' => '2015-07-01',
            'working_hour_template_id' => '3'
        ),
        'WorkingHourTemplate' => array(
            'color' => 'red',
            'id' => '3'
        )
    )
)
```

This filter function only returns the `DetailedWorkingHour` object, but I need to have both as a returned array

```
var filteredResult = filterByProperty(hours, "date", formattedDate);

function filterByProperty(array, prop, value){
    var filtered = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        var obj = array[i];

        for(var key in obj){
            if(typeof(obj[key] == "object")){
                var item = obj[key];

                if(item[prop] == value){
                    filtered.push(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }    
    return filtered;
}
```

How can I have both objects in the returned array?

Comment: what language is your array in?

Comment: Push `obj` into `filtered` instead of `item`.

Comment: The array is properly JSON formatted. The output above is the debugging output of CakePHP.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you posted the JSON instead of PHP, so we can paste it into a Javascript window.

Comment: What is `hours`? What is `formattedDate`? What is "both" in "I need to have both as a returned array"? Why do you include a dubugging output of CakePHP instead of JS code?

Comment: So, you have an array (L1) of arrays (L2), each L@ array has two associative sub arrays of its own (L3), and you want to return a sub array of one type of the L3 associative arrays while maintaining the integrity of your L2 arrays, do I have that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push `obj` into the `filtered` array instead of `item`.

```
function filterByProperty(array, prop, value){
    var filtered = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        var obj = array[i];

        for(var key in obj){
            if(typeof(obj[key] == "object")){
                var item = obj[key];

                if(item[prop] == value){
                    filtered.push(obj);
                    break; // So we only push the object once if multiple matches
                }
            }
        }
    }    
    return filtered;
}
```

Comment: Thx Barmar, that fixed the problem :) Really appreciate it.